# Handling intents serially between 2 apps

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, fragmenttransaction

I got 2 applications. A user of the first application can open a dialog in which he got 2 options of actions he could do. This is done like this:

```
public void sendSms(String number)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

public void call(String number)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

The second app has intent filter and it identifies this action:

```
<activity android:name="com.my.path.MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:launchMode="singleTask" >


 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter android:priority="100" >

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />

    </intent-filter>    
</activity>
```

The second application handles the intents like this:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent inten)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CALL))
    {
        *here make a fragment transaction to the fragment which handles calls *
    }
    else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO))
    {
        *here make a fragment transaction to the fragment which handles sms*

    }
}
```

When the user opens the first application and chooses one of the actions, it works fine and when he presses the back button he goes back to the first application which is also what I want. When he goes back to the first application, the dialog is still open like it was when he pressed the action.

The problem is that if the user press the call action again to call the second app, the second app is coming to the foreground, but it doesn't seem that the `onNewIntent` is called again, thus the fragment transaction does not happen.

I then noticed that for the second time the `onCreate` method is invoked so I tried handling the intent there. It did work for the SENDTO action but not for the CALL action. For the CALL action, the onCreate intent handling is being called but for some reason the fragment transaction does not work there (while like I said, the fragment transaction for SENDTO action does work).

Why isn't the `onNewIntent` method called when trying to do the same action again? And why won't the transaction work for the call action?

UPDATE: the fragment transaction now do work in the onCreate method. However I'd still prefer to handle everything in `onNewIntent`

Comment: Are you calling `finish()`? Have you looked in the logcat to see if the app is crashing? Android will only call `onCreate()` if it created a new instance of your `Activity`. Android won't create a new instance if there is already an instance active (alive).

Comment: The app does not crash and I don't call finish(). The app is simply in the background until the other one sends it an intent.

Answer (score 1):

This is decided by android frameworks, You can test it by observe Activity. When you first launch app, `onCreate` function will be called, meanwhile `onNewIntent` will not be called. Then click home menu, the activity works on the background. Now you start same intent again, `onNewIntent` will be called, however `onCreate` will not be called.

So I suggest: Just save data from intent(`Uri uri = intent.getData()`), at `onCreate` and `onNewIntent`. At `onResume` function, handle the data of intent you get.

Hope to help you.

Comment: but this is not the case.. I'm talking about the intent receiving app already running. Then it gets the intent and onNewIntent is called. After that it get another intent and suddenly onNewIntent does not being called but onCreate DOES get called. Why won't onNewIntent called after the first time it was invoked?

Comment: Maybe the activity has been killed by system, So it call `onCreate` again. In my suggest way, no matter `onCreate` or `onNewIntent` call, just save the intent's data. anyway, it must be called one.

Comment: I don't need to save any data, just need to make a fragment transaction. Like I wrote, the first intent is calling onNewIntent and I just want the second intent to do it as well since I don't know if I can't rely that onCreate will always be called.

Comment: He suggested to have `onCreate() { theData = intent.getData() }` and `onNewIntent() { theData = intent.getData() }` and then in `onResume() { soSomethingWithTheData() }` as `onResume` will always get called after the two. ... which is not true, as `onNewIntent` might get called when the activity is already open but maybe not in your case.